# javafx 1.3 listview

Tags: javafx

I want to display data from database. There is no TableView in javaFx 1.3 so I used ListView. But, when I put textbox in the listview, it does not perform well. I get problems in fetching data. Can anyone give me a code for listview with a textbox in it and it also fetches and updates data.

Answer (score 1):

```
var lv_dept_nm:String = "";

var lv_dept_des:String = "";

var lv_dept_name:TextBox;

var lv_dept_desc:TextBox;

var lv_dept_upBtn: Button;

var lv_dept_flag:Boolean = false;

var lv_dept_ind: Integer;

var lv_dept_len: Integer = 0;

var lv_dept_size:Integer = 0;

function removeLastChar(str: String)

{

    var string;

    if(str != "")
    {
        string = str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
    }
    else
    {
        string = str;
    }
    return string;
}

var viewDepartmentListView: ListView = ListView 

{

        items: bind [dept_choicebox_item]

        layoutInfo: LayoutInfo{height:bind lv_dept_size}
        layoutX: 170
        layoutY: 150
        width: 500
        cellFactory: function() {
            var listCell: ListCell;           

            if(dept_choicebox_item.size() > 5)
            {
                lv_dept_size = 55 * 5;
            }
            else
            {
                lv_dept_size = 55 * dept_choicebox_item.size();
            }
            listCell = ListCell {
                node : HBox {
                    width: 200
                    content: [
                         VBox {
                            spacing: 10
                            content: [
                                Label {
                                    text: bind dept_choicebox_item[listCell.index]
                                    visible: bind not listCell.empty and not lv_dept_flag or not listCell.selected or (lv_dept_ind != listCell.index)
                                }
                                lv_dept_name = TextBox
                                {
                                    promptText: bind dept_choicebox_item[listCell.index]
                                    onKeyPressed: function(ke: KeyEvent)
                                    {
                                        if(ke.code.toString() == "VK_BACK_SPACE")
                                        {
                                            lv_dept_len = lv_dept_nm.length();
                                            lv_dept_nm = removeLastChar(lv_dept_nm);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    onKeyTyped: function(e:KeyEvent)
                                    {
                                        if(lv_dept_len != 0)
                                        {
                                            lv_dept_len = 0;
                                        }
                                        else if(lv_dept_nm == "")
                                        {
                                            lv_dept_nm = e.char;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            lv_dept_nm = '{lv_dept_nm}{e.char}';
                                        }
                                    }

                                    columns: 12
                                    visible:bind not listCell.empty and lv_dept_flag and listCell.selected and (lv_dept_ind == listCell.index)
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                         VBox {
                            spacing: 10
                            content: [
                                Label {
                                    text: bind description[listCell.index]
                                    visible: bind not listCell.empty and not lv_dept_flag or not listCell.selected or (lv_dept_ind != listCell.index)
                                }
                                lv_dept_desc = TextBox
                                {
                                    promptText: bind description[listCell.index]
                                    onKeyPressed: function(ke: KeyEvent)
                                    {
                                        if(ke.code.toString() == "VK_BACK_SPACE")
                                        {
                                            lv_dept_len = lv_dept_des.length();
                                            lv_dept_des = removeLastChar(lv_dept_des);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    onKeyTyped : function(e: KeyEvent)
                                    {
                                        if(lv_dept_len != 0)
                                        {
                                            lv_dept_len = 0;
                                        }
                                        else if(lv_dept_des == "")
                                        {
                                            lv_dept_des = e.char;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            lv_dept_des = '{lv_dept_des}{e.char}';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    columns: 12
                                    visible:bind not listCell.empty and lv_dept_flag and listCell.selected and (lv_dept_ind == listCell.index)
                                }                                
                            ]
                        }
                        VBox{
                            spacing: 10
                            content: [
                                Button {
                                    vpos: VPos.TOP;
                                    text: "Edit"
                                    visible: bind not listCell.empty and (not lv_dept_flag or not listCell.selected or (lv_dept_ind != listCell.index))
                                    action: function() {
                                        lv_dept_ind = listCell.index;
                                        lv_dept_flag = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                lv_dept_upBtn = Button {
                                    vpos: VPos.TOP;
                                    text: "Update"
                                    visible: bind not listCell.empty and lv_dept_flag and listCell.selected and (lv_dept_ind == listCell.index)
                                    action: function() {
                                        cs = cn.prepareCall("call update_dept(?,?,?)");
                                        cs.setString(1, '{dept_choicebox_item[listCell.index]}');
                                        cs.setString(2, '{lv_dept_nm}');
                                        cs.setString(3, '{lv_dept_des}');
                                        cs.executeUpdate();
                                        dept_choicebox_item[listCell.index] = lv_dept_nm;
                                        description[listCell.index] = lv_dept_des;
                                        lv_dept_flag = false;
                                        lv_dept_nm = "";
                                        lv_dept_des = "";
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                        VBox{
                            spacing: 10
                            content: [
                                Button {
                                    vpos: VPos.TOP;
                                    text: "Delete"
                                    visible: bind not listCell.empty and (not lv_dept_flag or not listCell.selected or (lv_dept_ind != listCell.index))
                                    action: function() {
                                        cs = cn.prepareCall("call delete_dept(?)");
                                        cs.setString(1,'{dept_choicebox_item[listCell.index]}');
                                        cs.executeUpdate();
                                        delete dept_choicebox_item[listCell.index] from dept_choicebox_item;
                                        delete description[listCell.index] from description;
                                        lv_dept_size = 55 * dept_choicebox_item.size();
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                        ]
                        }            
            }
        }
        visible:true;
    };
```